# jquery bootstrap multple plugin $support.transition "conflict"

Tags: jquery, plugins, twitter-bootstrap, carousel

I am pretty new to bootstrap, jquery and client side. I am using the modals plugin already in my site. Every is fine...until I am trying to use the carousel plugin also.

$support.transition is being set to true in the modals.js code.

```
$(document).ready(function () {
    $.support.transition = (function () {
        var thisBody  = document.body || document.documentElement,
            thisStyle = thisBody.style,
            support   = thisStyle.transition !== undefined || thisStyle.WebkitTransition !== undefined || thisStyle.MozTransition !== undefined || thisStyle.MsTransition !== undefined || thisStyle.OTransition !== undefined

        return support
    })()
```

Inside this file, I noticed there are code for popups and other features(but not carousel). I downloaded this js file from teh site. Are you supposed to delete other unwanted features? where is the above code supposed to reside if I have mulitple plugins from the same comapny?

Comment: problem went away after I updated to version 2 for all bootstrap files

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use this file https://github.com/twitter/bootstrap/blob/master/js/bootstrap-transition.js

Comment: Your link is now dead. :(

Comment: Just choose different version, for instance https://github.com/twbs/bootstrap/blob/v2.3.2/js/bootstrap-transition.js

Comment: what if I'm on BS 3.3.0?

Comment: @SergeVelikanov try this one https://github.com/twbs/bootstrap/blob/v3.3.0/js/transition.js